# Django - How and Where to sort self-referencing model by function

Tags: django, sorting, django-forms, django-views

I have a self-referencing model "Location" like this :

```
class Location(BaseArticle):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_location = models.ForeignKey("self",
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True,
                                        help_text="Fill in if this location is a smaller part of another location.",
                                        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = HTMLField(blank=True,
                            null=True,
                            help_text="A description of the location and important features about it")

    def __str__(self):
        parent_location_string = ""
        parent_location = self.parent_location
        while parent_location is not None:
            parent_location_string = f'{parent_location.name} - {parent_location_string}'
            parent_location = parent_location.parent_location

        return f'{parent_location_string}{self.name}'
```

Now when I use Locations with generic Update/Create Views I get a drop-down menu of all locations, since they're ForeignKeys and that's just how generic views and forms handle ForeignKeys.

I would like to have the list of locations in the dropdown alphabetically sorted, but not by the name-field of a location, but by it's `__str__()` method, e.g. through `sorted(location_list, key=lambda x:str(x))`.

Time is generally not an issue, I am working with small datasets (<500 entries) that are unlikely to grow beyond 500.

What I tried so far:

- Since I'm trying to sort with a function, I can't sort in the model through the Meta classes "ordering" option
- Sorting in the Manager by overwriting `get_queryset()` and using `sorted()` loses me all the abilities of queryset objects, since `sorted()` returns a list. I use these functionalities (e.g. exclude/filter) fairly often, so I would like to keep them to avoid a lot of rewriting.
- Sorting in the View/Form by overwriting something in the generic `UpdateView` and `CreateView` or overwriting something from their used FormClasses (I am not that familiar with manipulating forms) before the template is rendered seems like the best option. The big question here is **what** needs to be overwritten, as I don't think it's "get_context_data".

Where should I perform this sorting ideally?
If it is in an Update/CreateView or a Form, what do I need to overwrite to do so?

Comment: You can not order a `QuerySet` by the `__str__` since the the `__str__` function is unknown in the database. The `__str__` method is also quite expensive, since it takes *O(d)* queries, with *d* the depth of the hierarchy. That thus means that for *n* items, the number of queries can scale worst case to *O(n^2)*, so ~1'250 queries.

Comment: Generally, yes. In this particular case as I am at the same time the one person managing the website and database, it is unlikely for the depth of such a lookup to go beyond 10, based on the nature of the locations-set.

For my purposes I definitely need a string that gives me the entire lineage of parent_locations for a given location, and I also want to sort by lineage. Since you pointed it out though I assume you're pointing me towards setting up a different field `parent_lineage` that stores such a string and handle updating/filling it in custom Create/Update views behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### you can build a recursion function to generate expression based on the below codes.

```py
Location.objects.annotate(
    order_name=Case(
        When(
            ~Q(parent_location__isnull=True), 
            then=Case(
                When(
                    ~Q(parent_location__parent_location__isnull=True), 
                    then=Concat('parent_location__parent_location__name', Value('-'), 'parent_location__name')
                ),
                default = Concat('parent_location__name', Value('-'), 'name'),
            )
        ),
        default = F('name'),
    )
)
```

or try a shot with the recursion function, Noqa

```py
def create_expression(self, fk_field_name, lookup, lookup_field_name, previous_lookup_list=[], depth=1, max_depth=3):
    slug = '__'
    query_lookup = slug.join([fk_field_name] * depth + [lookup])
    next_lookup_list = [slug.join([fk_field_name] * depth + [lookup_field_name]), Value('-')]

    if not previous_lookup_list:
        previous_lookup_list = [lookup_field_name]
    next_lookup_list.extend(previous_lookup_list)
    
    if depth == 1:
        default_exp = F(lookup_field_name)
    else:
        default_exp = Concat(*previous_lookup_list)

    if depth >= max_depth:
        return (
            Case(
                When(
                    ~Q(**{query_lookup: True}),
                    then = Concat(*next_lookup_list)
                ),
                default = default_exp
            )
        )

    return (
        Case(
            When(
                ~Q(**{query_lookup: True}),
                then= self.create_expression(fk_field_name, lookup, lookup_field_name, next_lookup_list, depth+1)
            ),
            default = default_exp
        )
    )
case_expression = create_expression('parent_location', 'isnull', 'name')
qset = Location.objects.annotate(order_name = case_expression).order_by('order_name')
```

or try this:

```py
objs = Location.objects.filter(parent_location__isnull = True).order_by('name')

def get_sub_objs(objs, level=1):
    for obj in objs.all():
        yield (obj, level)
        sub_objs = obj.location_set.all()
        if sub_objs:
            yield get_sub_objs(sub_objs, level+1)

for obj, level in get_sub_objs(objs):
    prefix = '-' * level
    print(prefix, obj.name)
```

Comment: I haven't come across annotate yet so I may be misinterpreting this. From the way I'm reading the code, I'm adding (annotating) a field to all Location objects called "order_name", the value of which is determined by the contents of "Case".
Is the idea to use it with querysets so that objects in a queryset have the "order_name" field, so that I can then use order_by to sort?

Comment: appending order_by('order_name')

Comment: Hmm could you maybe give me a hint on how to do a recursion with django's models? I'm familiar with how to write some in general, but I keep not getting the Syntax when it comes to mixing that with Django's SQL queries. I need to pass the recursive function always the given point of the queryset on where I am in the recursion so that from there I can start the next recursion level that checks whether its parent is null and return a default if that's the case, or triggers the next recursion level with that one's parent.

Comment: I feel my code is not a good choice in performance because Concat is expensive.

Comment: try my new method.

Comment: Personally I liked your first approach, because I could just attach it to a Manager for Location and thus any queryset coming from Location would be sorted this way. That would solve my issue on not knowing where and how in my code to sort.

With the second approach I'm not sure how I'd use it to sort. Or rather, where and in which part of the code (Model? Manager? View?) you intend to have it used for sorting.

Comment: if you use Select-widget for form and just sort it once, I think the second way could be better and more lightweight. You can get choices by yielding items by the generator. of course, you should refine the code.

Comment: try a shot as you intend